# JList to list toString() of an ArrayList of Objects

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, arraylist, jlist

I have an ArrayList of objects (A class called OrderItem). OrderItem has a toString() method in it.

I also have a GUI class in which I have a JList. I want to list all the toString()'s for the elements of the arrayLists.

I know that for an arrayList of strings you can make them show in a JList by using:

```
ArrayList<String> myArrayList  = new ArrayList<String>();
myArrayList.add("Value1");
myArrayList.add("Value2");
myJList = new JList(myArrayList.toArray());
```

But I want to list the toString() methods of an object arrayList, i.e. have something like:

```
ArrayList<OrderItem> myArrayList  = new ArrayList<OrderItem>();
myJList = new JList(myArrayList.toString());
```

I realise that there is a possibility that JList doesn't support such a feature or that there is some sort of logic problem with this. If that is so could you inform me as to why? Because surely an arrayList of strings should work in a similar way to an object arrayList's toString(). I merely want to be pulling out a String value for the elements and using those values for my list.

I've searched the web for an answer and have not been able to find one that helps me, so I've come here to try to get this resolved.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `JList` shows the `toString` value of the object. So there is no need to convert your objects to strings.

You can override that behavior of `JList` if needed by creating custom cell renderers. See [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more details.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot! I stupidly never through to try adding elements of an the ArrayList to the JList in the same way you add in Strings. In other words, I didn't realise it shows the toString by default. Cheers =)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the list to an array and then put it in the list.

```
ArrayList<OrderItem> myArrayList  = new ArrayList<OrderItem>();
OrderItem[] items = new OrderItem[myArrayList.size()];
myArrayList.toArray(items);
myJList = new JList(items);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the toArray() method displays each item in the arrayList.  JList doesn't show anything by default.  You have to set the visibility according to your needs.

It sounds like you are trying to simply display the object's toString method in the list instead of the full object; in other words, you simply want to display the string representation. instead of the array representation.

You can rewrite the array to represent the data you want to show (provide the "toString construct as the array is built):

```
ArrayList<> myNewArrayList =  new ArrayList<OrderItem>();
for (int i=0; i< oldArray.size(); i++)
{    
    newArray.add(oldArray.get)i).toString(); 
}
    ...  rest of code  ...
```

Then use the new array in the panel and use the index as reference to the object array for object processing.

HTH
LLB